# Python app is not creating entry in database

Tags: python, tkinter

I have trouble with my code. This code should create entry in database but it's not working. Do you see where I have made a mistake?
Or is it easier to create new entry in Excel instead and save this file in C drive and every time when data is entered it just updates it, if yes, how then it should look like?
Also maybe you have some other suggestion what should I change.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
root.title("TOOL")

Germany_other_team = StringVar()
Austria_other_team = StringVar()
Germany_self_solved = StringVar()
Austria _self_solved = StringVar()
Assigned_to_other_colleague = StringVar()
Reopened_by_user = StringVar()
SCTASK = StringVar()



def database():
   de_other= Germany_other_team.get()
   at_other= Austria_other_team.get()
   de_self= Germany_self_solved.get()
   at_self= Austria_self_solved.get()
   other_coll=Assigned_to_other_colleague.get()
   reopen_user=Reopened_by_user.get()
   task=SCTASK.get()
   conn = sqlite3.connect('Form.db')
   with conn:
      cursor=conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Incident (Germany (to other team) TEXT, Austria(to other team) TEXT, Germany (self solved) TEXT, Austria (self solved) TEXT,Assigned to other colleague TEXT, Re-opened by user TEXT, SCTASK TEXT)')
      cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Incident (Germany (to other team), Austria (to other team), Germany (self solved), Austria (self solved),Assigned to other colleague, Re-opened by user,SCTASK) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(de_other,at_other,de_self,at_self,other_coll,reopen_user,task,))
      conn.commit()



label_0 = Label(root, text="TOOL",width=20,font=("bold", 20))
label_0.place(x=90,y=53)


label_1 = Label(root, text="Germany (to other team)",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_1.place(x=80,y=130)

entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_1.place(x=240,y=130)

label_2 = Label(root, text=" Austria (to other team)",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_2.place(x=68,y=180)

entry_2 = Entry(root)
entry_2.place(x=240,y=180)

label_3 = Label(root, text=" Germany (self solved)",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_3.place(x=70,y=230)

entry_3 = Entry(root)
entry_3.place(x=235,y=230)

label_4 = Label(root, text=" Austria (self solved)",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_4.place(x=60,y=280)

entry_4 = Entry(root)
entry_4.place(x=240,y=280)

label_5 = Label(root, text="Assigned to other colleague",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_5.place(x=70,y=330)

entry_5 = Entry(root)
entry_5.place(x=235,y=330)

label_6 = Label(root, text="Re-opened by user",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_6.place(x=70,y=380)

entry_6 = Entry(root)
entry_6.place(x=240,y=380)

label_7 = Label(root, text="SCTASK",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_7.place(x=115,y=430)

entry_7 = Entry(root)
entry_7.place(x=240,y=430)


Button(root, text='Submit',width=20,bg='brown',fg='white').place(x=130,y=480)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should put the `cursor.execute(...)` and `conn.commit()` inside the `with conn:` block.

Comment: @acw1668 I did edit in my code now, but still it does not create this database file.

Comment: The field names may be invalid.  Try surrounding them by ''.

Comment: @JuliusC ***"it's not working."***: This is not helpful, [edit] your question and explain in detail and show any error message.

Comment: Your code does not modify those `StringVar`s and `database()` has never been called.

Comment: `Austria _self_solved`, that is invalid syntax, you cannot have space in a variable name. 2 - You do not have anywhere in your code where the `database` function is being called. 3 - You do not have anywhere in your code where the `Stringvars` to be written to the db are being edited or set. You have some more work to do before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the get function from Tkinter, get() as far as I know only really works for Entry and Text widgets, you are trying to get text from a Label.

To get the value out of a label, you can use the `cget` method, which can e used to get the value of the configuration options.

For example:

```
l = Label(text = "How are you?")
...
de_other = l.cget("text")
```

which will make `de_other` whatever was set to text in your labels.

Your program will probably be entering something into the database as there is no error, in this case, it will just be entering nothing.